# URLDownload aborts prematurely

Tags: warning-messages, web-access

So I've been trying to automate the download and build of various large packages for hooking *Mathematica* into extensions but the downloads continually finish prematurely.

Trying to get the Psi4 installer:

```
URLDownload@"http://www.psicode.org/downloads/Psi4conda2-latest-MacOSX.sh"
```

gives a `Transferred a partial file` message and returns a failure object:

[image: screenshot]

This is probably because the file is huge (~185 MB).

Unfortunately I can't be 100% sure this is *Mathematica* as curl has the same issue and, maybe, `URLDownload` is implemented on top of curl. (I'm running *Mathematica* 11. on OSX.)

In any case, does anyone know whether it's possible to get around this or am I forced to tell users that they need to download the packages themselves?

Comment: Type that URL into your browser.  Does it work for you?  Doesn't for me, I get a "file not found" type page, which is what is downloaded

Comment: Ah yeah that one's faulty. It was occurring with one that did exist the other day. Let me find that one.

Comment: If I run `URLDownload["https://cmake.org/files/v3.7/cmake-3.7.2-Darwin-x86_64.tar.gz", "~/cmake-3.7.2-Darwin-x86_64.tar.gz"]` then I get a 26MB file in my home directory

Comment: Nice to know this one was just me being dumb though.

Comment: @JasonB. Changed up the example. This thing is huge, unfortunately, but that's probably also the source of the abort.

Comment: @JasonB When I use URLDownload on it I get ~45MB of file. And curl works with it too, just partially.

Comment: do you get something like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/9FhMO.png ?

Comment: Yeah. And there's a checksum line in the script that that says it should be 194361831 bytes large while it's only ~45MB.

Comment: Can not check atm but what if you change CinnectionTimeout option?

Comment: @Kuba unfortunately that doesn't change anything.

Comment: I get the same with version 11.1.0 on Windows 7 x64. Crome 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit) also can't download complete file: only 57183554 bytes is saved. May be it is a "feature" of the server?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I don't know. It may well have been. I think I might have had trouble with curl and Chrome too. In any case I'm now pretty confident that whatever curl can do Mathematica can too, because it's basically using it.

Comment: I have tried to download the file with Firefox and it failed too: only 36145154 bytes file is created. I'll try `wget` right now: it prints useful diagnostic messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get the same with version 11.1.0 on Windows 7 x64. Crome 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit) also can't download complete file: only 57183554 bytes is saved. Firefox failed too: only 36145154 bytes file is created.

`Wget` prints useful diagnostic information, and what it says:

After downloading 18% `wget` printed that connection is closed at position 36472034 bytes (after 70 seconds), and started new download attempt from that position (not downloading again what was already downloaded). And at position 78421764 bytes the connection was closed again (after 69 more seconds), and then at 112892134 bytes again (after 68 more seconds), and than at 155620904 bytes (after 67 more seconds), then at 177263754 bytes (after 67 more seconds). Then the downloading was finished (the last attempt taken 42 seconds).

From `wget`s output it looks like the server is configured to kick the connection if it takes longer than 67 - 70 seconds... The only workaround is to use a tool which is able to resume downloading, like `wget`.

Comment: In the end I just downloaded the source code with git and compiled it because it came sparser and that worked out fine for me. It would be an interesting feature for them to introduce to Mathematica, though, some way to auto-resume upon closure.

Comment: Yes, it would be very nice to have this feature in *Mathematica*.